# Behat 2.4 outputs nothing (with Symfony2Extension)

Tags: symfony-2.1, behat

I'm currently migrating from behat 2.3 and BehatBundle to behat 2.4 and Symfony2Extension.

My problem is : behat outputs nothing when I run `php bin/behat`.

like :

```
$ php bin/behat
$
```

It seems to crash in `Behat\Behat\Console\BehatApplication::createContainer` when compiling the container, but got no errors.

Anyone knows this issue ?

Answer (score 2):

Provide as argument to `bin/behat` a bundle name of the suite you want to run.

Comment: It doesn't solve my problem, it seems to be a swift autoload problem silented by `@` in app/autoload.php.

Comment: Have you read the migration guide and updated app/autoload.php file? http://extensions.behat.org/symfony2/migrating_from_2.3_to_2.4.html